# How to detect changes in a list of drop down elements?

Tags: angular

I have a list of users. Each user is a composite object: `{ id: '123', name: 'Bob', State: 'Colorado' }`

I render those users using an *ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let u in users">
    {{ u.name }}
    <select [(ngModel)]="u.state">
       <option *ngFor="let s in states" [value]="s">{{s}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When select-value changes - I want to save the object over REST API.

I tried adding `(change)="changeState(u)"`, but that does not work, apparently `u.state` is being updated after my `(change)` callback is executed.

If I would not have a loop, I would give my dropdown a reference: `#state` and then use `(change)="changeState(u, state.value)"`

Is my only option is to use `$event.target.value`? Or is there a slicker way to do this? This solution also takes away validation.

Is any of the first two solution attempts salvageable?

Comment: Are you saving the before state or the after state? (new or old value).

Comment: With ngModel you can't do that, it has only two-way binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the `ngModelChange` event from `ngModel`:

```
<select [ngModel]="u.state" (ngModelChange)="changeState($event)">
       <option *ngFor="let s in states" [value]="s">{{s}}</option>
</select>
```

then the new select value  will be passed to `changeState()` directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using then you can go with

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let u in users">
    {{ u.name }}
    <select formControlName="dropdown" (change)="modelChange($event)">
       <option *ngFor="let s in states" [value]="s">{{s}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
modelChange(event){
console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: if I am using what?

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I used `(ngModelChange)="changeState($event)"` which works perfectly but in some scenario, the call to rest API was going Infinite time so another solution for that problem is that I change `(ngModelChange) to (selectionChange)` which work perfectly